# Python tkinter - Can't Add and delete selected list items in a listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Background: Hi, I im working on a tkinter UI written in python. The goal is to have a tkiner application that can add multiple data appended in to a list. Then add/insert the list in to the listbox. Have another feature that then removes the selected item from the listbox.

Problem: I can add a list as item to the listbox and remove selected items from the listbox. The problem starts when I have added and removed items, Then try to add new items. All I get is an Error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hugom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/hugom/OneDrive/Documents/pluralsight/notes/tkiner.py", line 17, in Save
    value = [entry.get() for entry in list_entry]  # gets the values writen in the "add ccount" pop window and stores it in a list
  File "c:/Users/hugom/OneDrive/Documents/pluralsight/notes/tkiner.py", line 17, in <listcomp>
    value = [entry.get() for entry in list_entry]  # gets the values writen in the "add ccount" pop window and stores it in a list
  File "C:\Users\hugom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2522, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".2963930148936.2963930149104" ```
````

I think the problem is in the way I add list as item by putting the both entrys data in a list and then add the list to the listbox.

Code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/wKRm79Pv

Comment: When you delete an item, do you remove it from your list?

Comment: dosnt listbox store the items, bcs I have a temporary list that stores the data before it inserts to the listbox.

Comment: When I run the code, I can't add an account, I get this error `[<tkinter.Entry object .!toplevel.!entry>, <tkinter.Entry object .!toplevel.!entry2>]`

Comment: @Farook It looks like this error is caused because the entry you are referring to does not exist, probably because you have deleted it. This means that you have not removed it from `list_entry`

Comment: so I need to empty the entry after or before every new entry?

Answer (score 0):

When you first add account,"list_entry" will have two elements. When u close the pop-up window, the "list_entry" still has two elements. When you add account again. the "list_entry" has four elements, because you closed the first pop-up window and you cannot reach first,second element. Then the code will throw this error.

There is two way to solve this:
1.Loop the list_entry and use `try ... except` , ignore the wrong element(not recommended)

```py
def Save():
    value = []
    for n in list_entry:
        try:
            v = n.get()
            value.append(v)
        except Exception as e:
            continue

    listbox.insert(END, value)
```

2.Every time when you call func Save(), clear the "list_entry" and destroy the pop-up window.

```py
def Save():
    value = [entry.get() for entry in list_entry]
    listbox.insert(END, value)
    while list_entry:
        list_entry.pop()
    pop.destroy()
```

Comment: In the code the function Save() uses to lists that stores and inserts the values to the listbox. list_entry:`[<tkinter.Entry object .2479035052104.2479035052272>, <tkinter.Entry object .2479035052104.2479035052440>]` and value: `['Username', 'pwd']` . Dont know who I shoudl change. Plus I tried clear them both in the Save() fucntion and in the clicker() where  they have been used.

Comment: i add some code u could try,see if  it work

Comment: I have solved it, u needed to empty the list_entry list at the Save() function